# Visual studio debugging error: Site can't be reached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

We are developing web site .net core 2 in Visual Studio 2017. That web project was working fine.
 Now I try to

> Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5) get an error: Site Can't be reached. 
> **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

How can i resolve this?

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwcAu.png)

Comment: [Check Here](https://appuals.com/best-fix-err_connection_reset/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might not have the right IIS settings installed. Take a look in your windows features. Make sure you have support for the right version on ASP.NET turned on which are available from control panel.

setting you may have [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa2ff.png)

you can check official document [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831475(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I figure you probably won't have the correct IIS settings introduced. Investigate your windows highlights. Ensure you have support for the correct form on ASP.NET diverted on which are accessible from the control board.

setting you may have [this way](https://antimalwareserviceexecutables.com/)

you can check the official archive here